# Какие бывают метрики?

Tags: распознавание, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, текст

Какие бывают метрики для определения схожести двух векторов из словосочетаний, зная схожесть между любыми 2-мя элементами. Например

- ("Сми", "телевидение", "телестудии и
     телекомпании")
- ("Общество", "Политика
     и общество", "средства массовой
     информации")

Answer (score 2):

Можно прогонять через словарь синонимов, приводя к стандартному виду (испльзуя для вычислений только по одному слову из группы синонимов). Затем можно строить для каждого набора слов частотную диаграмму (в самом простом случае диаграмма из нулей и единиц показывающая, есть слово или нет слова). И уже потом сравнивать гистограммы между собой, допустим, используя формулу корреляции, или, если используется битовая гистограмма, есть аналог корреляции, называющийся мерой Танимото.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте покопать в сторону fuzzy sets.   Там есть такое понятие как "расстояние Хемминга"